# Change Material in MeshRenderer

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a number of materials in my project and there paths are listed as followed:

- Assets/3DModels/Materials/01 - white.mat
- Assets/3DModels/Materials/02 - black.mat
- Assets/3DModels/Materials/03 - red.mat
- Assets/3DModels/Materials/04 - green.mat
- Assets/3DModels/Materials/05 - blue.mat
- Assets/3DModels/Materials/06 - purple.mat

I also have some 3D models created using 3ds max and imported into Unity. The models have the component Mesh Renderer, which contains an array called Materials. As set in 3ds max, all the models use 01 - white.mat as Element0 in array Materials.

During runtime, I want to change the Element0 of the array Materials to 04 - green.mat using C# script. Thus, I have the following code:

```
public void changeMaterial(){
    MeshRenderer mr = this.Transform.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    mr.material =  Resources.Load("3DModels/Materials/04 - green.mat", typeof(Material)) as Material;
}
```

When I run it, the Element0 of the object becomes None(Material). I think the there are some mistakes in my code. Please help, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, many thanks to Bart.

As Bart mentioned, I put the folder `3DModel` under `Resources` folder. In my program, I changed a little bit, so I have

```
Resources.Load("3DModels/Materials/04 - green", typeof(Material)) as Material;
```

There's no need to put `Assets/Resources/` at the front as `Resources.Load` always search assets in this folder. There's also no need to put `.mat` And now I can change the materials.

Again, many thanks to Bart

Answer (score 1):

If you want assets to be available at run-time and load them via a `Resources.Load()` call, [you'll have to put them in a Resources folder](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html). So put them in something like

```
Assets/Resources/3DModels/Materials
```

In addition your code has one other little snag. Some of the properties in Unity behave in an unexpected manner. In this case, setting a material won't work. You'll have to create an array of materials (even if it has just one element) and assign it to `mr.materials`.

I believe that with those corrections it should work.

Comment: Sorry, it still fails. Are there anything I have to setup beforehand?

Comment: I overlooked an issue. Updated the answer.